# Multiple value search by middle table

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

i have these free tables:

```
Record
+--+----------+
|id|created_at|
+--+----------+
|1 |2017-12-26|
+--+----------+
|2 |2017-12-27|
+--+----------+

Parameters
+--+----------+
|id|field_name|
+--+----------+
|1 |First name|
+--+----------+
|2 |Last name |
+--+----------+

Records_Parameters
+--+---------+------------+-----+
|id|record_id|parameter_id|value|
+--+---------+------------+-----+
|1 |1        |1           |John |
+--+---------+------------+-----+
|2 |1        |2           |Smith|
+--+---------+------------+-----+
|3 |2        |1           |Joe  |
+--+---------+------------+-----+
|4 |2        |2           |Smith|
+--+---------+------------+-----+
```

And I can't figure out how to write a query to search by parameters:

For example:

1.
`First name = John` and `Last name = Smith` i should get `Record id: 1,2`

2.
`First name = Joe` and `Last name = Smith` i should get `Record id: 2`

Count of parameters will change.

Thanks in advance.

---

**UPDATED**:

I tried:

`SELECT r.id
FROM Records_Parameters as rp
JOIN Parameters p on (rp.parameter_id = p.id)
JOIN Record r on (r.id = rp.record_id)
WHERE 1
    AND (rp.parameter_id = 1 and rp.value like "%John%"
    AND rp.parameter_id = 2 and rp.value like "%Smith%");`

===

`[..]
WHERE 1
    AND rp.parameter_id = 1 and rp.value like "%John%"
    AND rp.parameter_id = 2 and rp.value like "%Smith%";`

===

`SELECT id
FROM records_params
WHERE 1
    AND (param_id = 1 AND value LIKE "%John%" 
    AND param_id = 2 AND value LIKE "%Smith%");`

No luck so far.

---

**UPDATED**:

@Gordon Linoff answered to original question, so I mark it as right answer.

Also I update this question with a little bit different solution and updated @Gordon Linoff query:

`SELECT rp.record_id
FROM Records_Parameters rp 
JOIN Parameters p on rp.parameter_id = p.id
WHERE (p.id = 1 AND (rp.value LIKE "%John%" OR rp.value LIKE "%Joe%")) OR (p.id = 2 AND rp.value LIKE "%Smith%")
GROUP BY rp.record_id
HAVING COUNT(distinct p.id) = 2;`

With this query search can be done by several fields, value can be searched by substring.

Comment: what did you try? This is a simple join over 3 tables with fk-ids:  `select * from Records_Parameters as rp join Parameters as p on rp.parameter_id = p.id join Record as r on r.id = rp.record_id where .... `  and then  you select the correct combination of ids from parameters and the value from record_parameters''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

One method uses `group by` and `having`:

```
select rp.record_id
from record_parameters rp join
     parameters p
     on rp.parameter_id = p.id
where (p.field_name, rp.value) in ( ('First name', 'John'), ('Last name', 'Smith') )
group by rp.record_id
having count(distinct p.field_name) = 2;
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond, but I forgot to mention that value should be searched by substring or whole string: *ohn, J*, Smi* and so on.

Comment: @DarjušIlcevič . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you ask.  It is rude to change a question after it has been answered, because that can invalidate answers, which can draw downvotes.

Comment: sorry, didn't know, my mistake. Marked updated info separately. No more updates. Please see updated question.